# Coordinates of nodes of an twisted hypercube

Tags: geometry

I'm looking for a way to calculate the nodal coordinates of an twisted n-cube. All searching up until now at the internet and literature ended up in a dead-end...

There are several conditions this twisted cube I'm looking for with arbitrary number of dimensions should fullfill:

- "twisted" means a rotation of 45° of half (?) of the nodes. Please see the [link1](https://reformationbouck.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/bt4.jpg) for a twisted cube in 3D. I think [link2](https://images1.sw-cdn.net/product/picture/625x465_15456038_2230506_1472005466.jpg) is shoing a projection of a twisted 4-cube.
- The length of all edges should be equal.
- In the end all nodes of the twisted hypercube have to be located at the surface of a hypersphere with center at origin and radius of 1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your first image (the 3d case), the condition of all edge lengths being equal is already violated: some of them are $\sqrt2$ longer than others. And your faces are no longer planar, which is something to keep in mind.

So what are the coordinates in the first image? One way to describe it would be as follows: stariing with the cube with corners $(x,y,z)=(\pm1,\pm1,\pm1)$ you take those at $(x,y,1)$ and rotate them by $45°$ to obtain $(\frac{x-y}{\sqrt2},\frac{x+y}{\sqrt2},1)$.

Doing the same in dimension $d$ you start with $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_d)=(\pm1,\dots,\pm1)$, then take the half with $x_3=1$ and move them to $(\frac{x_1-x_2}{\sqrt2},\frac{x_1+x_2}{\sqrt2},1,x_4,\dots,x_d)$. So you have one designated plane direction where you rotate (namely the $x_1$-$x_2$-plane) and one designated direction which you use to split the cube into two halfs (namely $x_3$).

As far as I can judge from the 4d projection, I'd say this fits what I did above. At least it looks to me as though the front left face of the outer and the inner cell were parallel, so that would be the plane of rotation. And the directin where the edges connect inner and outer cell is the one used to distinguish the part to be rotated, as the inner cell is rotated against the outer.

If you really wanted to make all edges have equal length, you could scale down the $x_3$ coordinates to compensate for the rotation.